# Raid Controller: Activating Write Back

Tags: raid, hardware-raid, raid5

We need to activate "write back"-mode on a raid controller in a storage server.
Do i need to reinstall the operating system or rebuild the raid setup after activating write back?
We can´t test it, because the server which needs to be configured is currently being used in our live environment.

Thanks for help.

Comment: You should provide information on the server's operating system, the make/model of the server and the specifics of the RAID controller.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you don't need to do any of this. Furthermore, you can even do (and this is preferable way of doing it in production) it without rebooting server or operation system. This is a common principle of operation of raid controllers.